# RSS to e-mail notifications?

Tags: email, rss

There's a web site that's supposed to upload a video I'd like to watch but it could be in several weeks.

The only way to be notified of any change is through RSS, but I don't use RSS at all, so installing an RSS client just for this seems overkill.

Unless there's a better solution I should know about, do you know of a good, free solution on the web that will watch the RSS channel and send me an e-mail when a new item was added?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a trigger from your rss to send an email to your email id in [ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com)

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that. Done.